# FFmpeg debug verbosity

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm debugging ffmpeg with -loglevel debug, and I want the debug messages (which are basically just printing to terminal the value of different variables) but in front of each line is the file offset in blue text, and I don't want to see that, because it's useless to me.

How can I do this?

Here's an example screenshot: 
[image]

I want the blue text [dca @ 0x7fe86c80f000] to be removed, but the green text to stay

I tried -nostats and -hide_banner together and apart, and that didn't work either.

Comment: In an *nix environment it would be easiest to pipe it's output through sed or cut. What OS are you working on?

Comment: I'm using OS X, the reason I'm printing the debug info using av_log is so it'll end up in a .log file, that I can review later to make sure everything is being read properly.

Answer (score 7):

As Nifle commented, you can use sed like this.  Without sed, if your output is:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avi -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k output.avi -loglevel debug

here is a line without any brackets and stuff, it should display too
[dca @ 0x7fe86c80f000] leave this stuff here
[dca @ 0x7fe86c80f000] and this
[dca @ 0x7fe86c80f000] this stuff too
another line that should just be printed plainly.
```

Then you can add

```
| sed 's/\[.*\] *\t*//'
```

to the end, like this:    (ran on my linux, osX sed may be ever-so-slightly different)

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.avi -b:v 64k -bufsize 64k output.avi -loglevel debug | sed 's/\[.*\] *\t*//'
here is a line without any brackets and stuff, it should display too
leave this stuff here
and this
this stuff too
another line that should just be printed plainly.
```

Look good?